LibMambaUnsatisfiableError while creating the enviroment of bob.paper.deep_pix_bis_pad.icb2019
While trying to create the conda enviroment of bob.paper.deep_pix_bis_pad.icb2019 i encounter this error after the command mamba env create -f environment.yml. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS using mamba + conda.
LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested zc.recipe.egg 2.0.5**
  - nothing provides requested zc.buildout 2.11.2**
  - nothing provides requested menpofit 0.5.0**
  - nothing provides requested menpo 0.8.1**
  - nothing provides requested libsvm 3.22**
  - nothing provides requested libblitz 1.0.1**
  - nothing provides requested cyvlfeat 0.4.6**
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.sp-2.0.12-py27h3b40046_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.measure-4.0.0-py27h74400ff_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.math-3.1.2-py27he85555e_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.mlp-2.1.8-py27hac2ea6f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.linear-2.1.4-py27hf9a62a4_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.libsvm-2.1.1-py27h7de4692_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.em-2.1.2-py27h5d07071_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.boosting-2.0.15-py27hf9a62a4_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.activation-2.0.12-py27hac2ea6f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.qualitymeasure-1.1.1-py27hcd7cccb_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.gabor-2.0.13-py27h5d07071_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.flandmark-2.1.8-py27hbf20c1f_0
  - nothing provides menpo >=0.8.1,<0.9.0a0 needed by bob.ip.facelandmarks-1.0.6-py27h8e9bb8c_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.facedetect-2.1.6-py27hbf20c1f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.draw-2.0.11-py27hbc316f1_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.color-2.0.12-py27hac2ea6f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.base-2.2.2-py27h2b31b38_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.video-2.1.1-py27hd1ff1a4_1
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.matlab-2.0.12-py27h5bf78fe_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.image-2.4.2-py27hd33571a_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.base-3.0.4-py27h12a88d4_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.core-2.2.1-py27hac2ea6f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.blitz-2.0.16-py27hac2ea6f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ap-2.1.7-py27h0191800_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.mlp-2.1.10-py36h2f0a336_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.boosting-2.0.15-py27hf9a62a4_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.learn.boosting-2.0.15-py27hf9a62a4_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.facedetect-2.1.6-py27hbf20c1f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.facedetect-2.1.6-py27hbf20c1f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.facedetect-2.1.6-py27hbf20c1f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.ip.facedetect-2.1.6-py27hbf20c1f_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.video-2.1.1-py27hd1ff1a4_1
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.video-2.1.1-py27hd1ff1a4_1
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.video-2.1.1-py27hd1ff1a4_1
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.base-3.0.4-py27h12a88d4_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.base-3.0.4-py27h12a88d4_0
  - nothing provides libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 needed by bob.io.base-3.0.4-py27h12a88d4_0
  - nothing provides matplotlib-base 3.0.2 py36h167e16e_1000 needed by matplotlib-3.0.2-h8a2030e_1000
  - package dlib-19.7-np18py27_blas_openblas_200 requires sqlite 3.13.*, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package vlfeat-0.9.21-h166bdaf_0 requires libgcc-ng >=10.3.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package libmatio-1.5.11-0 requires hdf5 1.8.18|1.8.18.*, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ bob.ap 2.1.7**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.bio.base 4.0.0**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.io.base >=3.0.4,<4.0a0 , which requires
│     └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.bio.face 4.0.0**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.learn.boosting >=2.0.15,<3.0a0 , which requires
│     └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.bio.video 3.4.2**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.learn.boosting >=2.0.15,<3.0a0 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.blitz 2.0.16**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.core 2.2.1**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.db.atnt 2.0.12**  is installable and it requires
│  └─ bob.io.image >=2.4.2,<3.0a0  with the potential options
│     ├─ bob.io.image [2.4.2|2.4.3|...|2.5.0] would require
│     │  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│     └─ bob.io.image 2.5.1 would require
│        └─ matplotlib >=3.4.3,<4.0a0 , which can be installed;
├─ bob.db.base 3.0.1**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.io.base [>=3.0.10,<4.0a0 |>=3.0.4,<4.0a0 |...|>=3.0.9,<4.0a0 ], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.db.mobio 2.2.1**  is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ bob.db.mobio 2.2.1 would require
│  │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ bob.db.mobio 2.2.1 would require
│     └─ bob.db.base >=3.0.1,<4.0a0  with the potential options
│        ├─ bob.db.base [3.0.1|3.0.2|...|3.1.0], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
│        └─ bob.db.base 3.2.0 would require
│           └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
├─ bob.db.msu_mfsd_mod 2.2.5**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.io.video >=2.1.1,<3.0a0 , which requires
│     └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.db.replay 3.0.5**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.io.video >=2.1.1,<3.0a0 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.db.replaymobile 1.1.5**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.io.video >=2.1.1,<3.0a0 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.io.base 3.0.4** , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.io.image 2.4.2** , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.io.matlab 2.0.12**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.io.video 2.1.1** , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.ip.base 2.2.2**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.ip.color 2.0.12**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.ip.dlib 1.0.5**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.ip.facedetect >=2.1.6,<3.0a0 , which requires
│     └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.ip.draw 2.0.11**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.ip.facedetect 2.1.6** , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.ip.facelandmarks 1.0.6**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ menpo >=0.8.1,<0.9.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.ip.flandmark 2.1.8**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.ip.gabor 2.0.13**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.ip.mtcnn 1.0.1**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.ip.facedetect >=2.1.6,<3.0a0 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.ip.qualitymeasure 1.1.1**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.ip.skincolorfilter 0.0.5**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.ip.facedetect >=2.1.6,<3.0a0 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.learn.activation 2.0.12**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.learn.boosting 2.0.15** , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.learn.em 2.1.2**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.learn.libsvm 2.1.1**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.learn.linear 2.1.4**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.learn.mlp 2.1.8**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.math 3.1.2**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.measure 4.0.0**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ bob.pad.base 2.1.0**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.learn.mlp >=2.1.8,<3.0a0 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.rppg.base 2.0.1**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ bob.ip.facedetect >=2.1.6,<3.0a0 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
├─ bob.sp 2.0.12**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ libblitz >=1.0.1,<1.0.2.0a0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ cyvlfeat 0.4.6**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ dlib 19.7**  is installable and it requires
│  └─ sqlite 3.13.* , which can be installed;
├─ hdf5 1.10.1**  is requested and can be installed;
├─ libblitz 1.0.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libgcc-ng 8.2.0**  is requested and can be installed;
├─ libmatio 1.5.11**  is not installable because it requires
│  └─ hdf5 1.8.18|1.8.18.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ libsvm 3.22**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ matplotlib 3.0.2**  is not installable because there are no viable options
│  ├─ matplotlib 3.0.2 would require
│  │  └─ matplotlib-base 3.0.2 py36h167e16e_1000, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ matplotlib 3.0.2 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ matplotlib 3.0.2 would require
│  │  └─ matplotlib-base 3.0.2 py36h167e16e_1001, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  └─ matplotlib 3.0.2 would require
│     └─ matplotlib-base 3.0.2 py37h167e16e_1001, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
├─ menpo 0.8.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ menpofit 0.5.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ python 3.6.8**  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ sqlite 3.26.0**  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ vlfeat 0.9.21**  is not installable because there are no viable options
│  ├─ vlfeat 0.9.21 would require
│  │  └─ libgcc-ng >=10.3.0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  └─ vlfeat 0.9.21 would require
│     └─ libgcc-ng >=12 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ zc.buildout 2.11.2**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
└─ zc.recipe.egg 2.0.5**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel).


I have tried to remove the versions in the enviroment.yml but if i do so it won't create the enviroment and remains stuck in loading.
